# How to see all bytes of a raw image

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, mfc, c++14

I am working with images in c++, i have a program that capture a image the result data is this

[image: Result image buffer]

then when a write the image in other folder I get this result:

[image: Result image written]

```
CFileException ex;

CFile file;
file.Open((LPCTSTR)"test", CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeNoTruncate, &ex);
file.Write(image.puc_image, lenOfImage)
```

when I open the file with the note.

so basically I want to manipulate the data that a write and convert to base 64 and then send to an API. 
but I never see all the data when a read the file. so the convention of base64 don't output correctly the data.

Comment: Can you use your debugger to look at the memory where you store the image - looks to be `image.puc_image` from your question?  That will show you raw bytes.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If you want to inspect the bytes, use a binary viewer (see Open With in VS IDE). If you want to read the pixels of an image and manipulate them, it is a lot more work.

Comment: Is it possible that your "result image buffer" is being printed as a C string? If so, even tough it might contain N bytes of data, you will only see until the first zero (NUL, '\0') byte

Comment: `(LPCTSTR)"test"` accomplishes one thing, and one thing only: It silences the compiler that would otherwise call out the exact location of the bug in your code.

Comment: You have no Base64 code yet? Can you show the image and the written file as hexadecimal display (e.g. with hex editor instead of notepad)? What would you expect exactly to be shown? The beginning is identical!

Comment: @MichaelDorgan when I use the debugger I see only the firsts bytes like the first image.

Comment: @zdf no the pixels, the bytes but from the code to manipulate

Comment: @IInspectable@JavierMartín
I will edit the post for better understand

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `CFile::typeBinary`

If the file is written in text mode, newlines could get mangled.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. in a few hours